# Need to Access Azure web services only through INTRANET

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I had developed an Azure WEB Application and published in Azure Web Services.

I need to restrict an access through internet and allow only to INTRANET.

Comment: In Azure Portal, Go to your App Services > Networking > IP Restriction > Add Role and provide your IPs of your LAN. Or you can have Web Services registered with Azure API manager for better management.

Comment: First you need to connect your intranet to a VNET inside Azure via a VPN or Express Route. Have you done that yet? Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 4):

Azure web app service is publicly accessed through the Internet. If you want to restrict an access through the internet and allow only to Intranet. You can put the Azure web app service in an [Internal Azure App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-ilb-ase) so that this Web App isn't publicly accessible as it is sitting in a subnet inside a Virtual Network and it isn't exposed to the internet. Also, The Azure app service can communicate with the on-premise environment via VPN. For more ref: [Networking considerations for an App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info)

However, the Isolated ASE is expensive. If you want it cheap and simple and the Web App does not need to access on-prem resources. You can put an [IP restriction](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/) in the web.config or use [AD authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication). Refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f472ab4d-7970-436d-9288-30023b69e456/web-app-with-intranet-access-only?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

Comment: Yes, I have Done IP restriction in AZURE WEB APP SERVICES, I had updated my intranet ip and ask it allow. it blocks other ip . but when i connect through AIRTEL Network , it still allows . i cant able to block . is any idea ?@Nancy Xiong - MSFT

Comment: What is your "intranet ip", Do you use VPN? If no VPN, The on-premise environment will use public IP to access the web app via NAT.

Comment: Once the ip’s are restricted only to intranet(organization users) then do we still need Azure firewall or App gateway services? Firewalls are mostly used to protects from internet website attacks. I don’t have access to ask questions that’s why asking here.

Comment: Yes, the Azure firewall mostly protects Internet attacks. For ILB ASE, if you want to let users access the websites in ILB ASE, you need to use azure app gateway to expose to the Internet access.